# How to extract numbers from string in Javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following string

```
/Date(1317772800000)/
```

I want to use a Javascript regular expression to extract the numerical portion of it

```
1317772800000
```

How is this possible?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with `yourString.substring(6,19)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be it

```
var numPart = "/Date(1317772800000)/".match(/(\d+)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for regex. Use .substring() function. In this case try:

```
var whatever = "/Date(1317772800000)/";
whatever = whatever.substring(6,whatever.length-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This'll do it for you: http://regex101.com/r/zR0wH4

```
var re = /\/Date\((\d{13})\)\//;
re.exec('/Date(1317772800000)/');
=> ["/Date(1317772800000)/", "1317772800000"]
```

If you don't care about matching the date portion of the string and just want extract the digits from any string, you can use this instead:

```
var re = /(\d+)/;
re.exec('/Date(1317772800000)/')
["1317772800000", "1317772800000"]
```

Comment: No it won't; this will match his entire string.

Comment: @AndrewArnold no... it won't. Check out the link...